# Stratio Error: Install selected technologies

Tags: apache, hadoop, mesos, marathon, stratio

I have downloaded the last version of Stratio platform.

Platform: Ubuntu, version 14.04. - 5 nodes.

Installed configuration:
  Installation type: Local hosts. From the  two options to install Stratio Manager I chose

(Use machines that comply the requirements providing ssh credentials (with root privileges).)

Configured OK.

Log in Stratio Manager. OK.

I see all my nodes. OK.

On Stage SELECT TECHNOLOGIES (any technologies: Zookeeper, Mesos, Kafka, ...) 
 and install I received FATAL ERROR: Running exception handlers.

Here are logs:

```
    [0m owner "root" 
    [0mend 
    [0m 
    [0m[2015-11-16T15:53:43+04:00] INFO: Running queued delayed notifications       before re-raising exception 
    [2015-11-16T15:53:43+04:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers 
    [2015-11-16T15:53:43+04:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete 
    [2015-11-16T15:53:43+04:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to    /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out 
    [2015-11-16T15:53:43+04:00] ERROR: java_ark[jdk] (java::oracle line 53) had   an error: SystemExit: exit 
    [2015-11-16T15:53:43+04:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1) 

**ERROR**
```

LOG TAKEN FROM /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out

```
Generated at 2015-11-16 15:53:43 +0400
SystemExit: java_ark[jdk] (java::oracle line 53) had an error: SystemExit: exit
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.14.6/lib/chef/application.rb:346:in `exit'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.14.6/lib/chef/application.rb:346:in `fatal!'
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/java/providers/ark.rb:164:in `block (2 levels) in class_from_file'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.14.6/lib/chef/mixin/why_run.rb:52:in `call'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.14.6/lib/chef/mixin/why_run.rb:52:in `add_action'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.14.6/lib/chef/provider.rb:156:in `converge_by'
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/java/providers/ark.rb:142:in `block in class_from_file'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.14.6/lib/chef/provider/lwrp_base.rb:138:in `instance_eval'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.14.6/lib/chef/provider/lwrp_base.rb:138:in `block in action'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.14.6/lib/chef/provider.rb:121:in `run_action'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.14.6/lib/chef/resource.rb:648:in `run_action'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.14.6/lib/chef/runner.rb:49:in `run_action'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.14.6/lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in converge'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.14.6/lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `each'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.14.6/lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `block in converge'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.14.6/lib/chef/resource_collection.rb:98:in `block in execute_each_resource'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.14.6/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:116:in `call'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.14.6/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:116:in `call_iterator_block'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.14.6/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:85:in `step'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.14.6/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:104:in `iterate'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.14.6/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:55:in `each_with_index'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.14.6/lib/chef/resource_collection.rb:96:in `execute_each_resource'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.14.6/lib/chef/runner.rb:80:in `converge'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.14.6/lib/chef/client.rb:345:in `converge'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.14.6/lib/chef/client.rb:431:in `do_run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.14.6/lib/chef/client.rb:213:in `block in run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.14.6/lib/chef/client.rb:207:in `fork'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.14.6/lib/chef/client.rb:207:in `run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.14.6/lib/chef/application.rb:236:in `run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.14.6/lib/chef/application/client.rb:338:in `block in run_application'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.14.6/lib/chef/application/client.rb:327:in `loop'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.14.6/lib/chef/application/client.rb:327:in `run_application'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.14.6/lib/chef/application.rb:55:in `run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.14.6/bin/chef-client:26:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/bin/chef-client:23:in `load'
/usr/bin/chef-client:23:in `<main>'
```

Please, if anybody know, help :)